# switch class in jQuery/JavaScript for active/inactive state

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What i want to do, is when you click 'sign in' it changes the 'sign up' button to an 'inactive' class and vice versa. So the button you have clicked on is white and stands out and the one that isn't being used is faded.

[Active/inactive state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0Aea.png)

as you can se eon the picture above, the signup form is inactive and the sign in form is active.

However the code I have now, when I click between the 2, both of them become 'active' and won't switch back.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.activebtn').click(function() {
    $('.activebtn').addClass("activebtn");
    $('.activebtn').removeClass("inactivebtn");
    $('.inactivebtn').removeClass('activebtn');
    $('inactivebtn').addClass('inactivebtn');
    $('#signup').slideUp("slow", function() {
      $('#signin').slideDown("slow");
    })
  })
});

$(function() {
  $('.inactivebtn').click(function() {
    $('.inactivebtn').removeClass("inactivebtn");
    $('.inactivebtn').addClass("activebtn");
    $('.activebtn').removeClass("activebtn");
    $('activebtn').addClass("inactivebtn");
    $('#signin').slideUp("slow", function() {
      $('#signup').slideDown("slow");
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.activebtn {
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.inactivebtn {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebarmenu">
  <h1><a class="activebtn" href="#">Sign In</a></h1>
  <h1><a class="inactivebtn" href="#">Sign Up</a></h1><br><br>
</div>
```

I think you can probably guess what I was trying to do here, but it didn't work as explained above.

Comment: Can you try to add . in class-selectors.

Comment: That didn't work mate, it's as if it's editing the local item so the item you 'click' so to speak, but not the other item.

Comment: There a couple of ok answers down there.  I think you want to be styling `.button` and `.button:disabled`.  Then you can use jQuery's `.prop("disabled", true)` (or false) within a `.click()` handler which determines which button to disable (i.e. the one that != this within the scope of the handler)

Comment: Oliver's your man, OP.  his answer is lovely and neat.

Comment: Yeah happy with the response from the community just now and got my problem solved very quickly... I've taken snippets and bookmarked the page so I can revisit when it comes to doing this sort of thing again. I will be trying out all the answers to see which works better :) Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with 2 classes: at first we should get rid of both of the classes, then set the default inactive state for elements and then set active state for the element where the click occured. Try this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#sidebarmenu a").on("click", function() {
        $(this).parents("#sidebarmenu").find("a").removeClass("activebtn inactivebtn").addClass("inactivebtn");;
        $(this).removeClass("inactivebtn").addClass("activebtn");
    });
});
```

```css
  .activebtn{
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.inactivebtn{
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebarmenu">
      <h1><a class="activebtn" href="#">Sign In</a></h1>
      <h1><a class="inactivebtn" href="#">Sign Up</a></h1><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Curveball, that works great! I added that code, and kept the transition using JQuery.

Answer (score 3):

You will be much better off using just one `.active`-class for the active, and a `.button`-class for all other (general) buttons.
Then, toggling the active state becomes as easy as it sounds:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.button').on('click', function() {
    $('.button').removeClass('active'); // reset *all* buttons to the default state
    $(this).addClass('active'); // mark only the click-target as active
  })
});
```

```css
.button.active{
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.button{
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebarmenu">
      <h1><a class="button active" href="#">Sign In</a></h1>
      <h1><a class="button" href="#">Sign Up</a></h1><br><br>
</div>
```

Comment: within your click handler isn't `$('.button')` the same as saying `$(this)`?  To me you handler looks like it's going to remove and add the active class to the same element

Comment: No. `$('.button')` will select all DOM elements with that class, whereas `this` (or `$(this)`, as a jQ-object) is bound to the event target.

Comment: Of course.  My bad, sorry - with my brain fart aside, this is definitely the most elegant solution

Answer (score 1):

Or you a .each loop and check what class is on the dom and perform your switch of classes.

```
$(".activebtn, .inactivebtn").each(function(index, key){
    if(key.className == "activebtn"){
       $(this).removeClass("activebtn").addClass("inactivebtn")
    }else if(key.className == "inactivebtn"){
       $(this).removeClass("inactivebtn").addClass("activebtn")        
    }
})
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
   $(".activebtn, .inactivebtn").each(function(index, key){
  if(key.className == "activebtn"){
     $(this).removeClass("activebtn").addClass("inactivebtn")
    }else if(key.className == "inactivebtn"){
     $(this).removeClass("inactivebtn").addClass("activebtn")        
    }
})
  }, 500)
})
```

```css
.activebtn {
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.inactivebtn {
  text-align: center;
  opacity: .5;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: opacity .5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="sidebarmenu">
  <h1><a class="activebtn" href="#">Sign In</a></h1>
  <h1><a class="inactivebtn" href="#">Sign Up</a></h1><br><br>
</div>
```